# how the query is processed?

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain step by step how this query is processed?

```
SELECT F.ID,
       F.FirstName,
       h.UserID,
       h.TYPE,
       L.UserID,
       L.LOGGEDIN
FROM   users AS F
       INNER JOIN history AS h
         ON h.USERID = F.ID
       LEFT JOIN Login AS L
         ON L.USERID = f.MONEY
```

If i remove the `L.UserID, L.LOGGEDIN and LEFT JOIN` it gives me this result:

```
SELECT F.ID,
       F.FirstName,
       h.UserID,
       h.TYPE
FROM   users AS F
       INNER JOIN history AS h
         ON h.USERID = F.ID
```

---

```
ID  FirstName   UserID  TYPE
6   rafal            6  A
6   rafal            6  A
6   rafal            6  A
5   rafal            5  B
```

Does it mean that the result is returned by the INNER Join in the very first step and it is further LEFT Joined?

Comment: Are you asking about the logical/conceptual steps or the actual physical operators that MySQL uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You could also write the `FROM` part of the query as:

```
FROM   ( users AS F
         INNER JOIN history AS h
           ON h.USERID = F.ID
       )
       LEFT JOIN Login AS L
         ON L.USERID = f.MONEY
```

if that helps you. This is how the `FROM` part is parsed.

Now the order or processing is first the `FROM` clause, then the `SELECT`. For more complicated queries it's:

```
FROM -> WHERE  -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> DISTINCT -> 
-> UNION -> ORDER BY -> OFFSET -> LIMIT
```

Notice that is does not mean that the DBMS will process the query in this order. It can choose to take a different path. No matter how it processes it though, the result set should be the same as if it was processed this way.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, yes, run `EXPLAIN` followed by your query and it will tell you.

Comment: I did but it didnt tell me that i could understand.

Comment: So, your question should be: can you explain the `EXPLAIN` output to me. Sure: first step is the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html) of course, and if that is a bit to impractical [this seems a reasonable intro](http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained). If after that you still feel unsure about some details, please provide the `EXPLAIN` output, and tell us what you do understand, and which parts you don't. (I would advise opening a new question for that).

Comment: @Wrikken I believe the OP was asking a general SQL question about how the `LEFT JOIN` works.

Comment: @YaK: might be, I interpreted as asking how the query execution plan works as far as I can gather. And by no means does the `right join` come before the `left join` in all cases here. MySQL may shuffle the query plan around a little depending on spread of indexes.

Comment: @Wrikken: correct, the question is indeed ambiguous, and needs clarification. I also agree that the "human" way of thinking the query does not reflect how the computation is actually performed by MySQL.